# Receiving message string with zmq in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, gps, zeromq

I am trying to connect a simple c++ client to a GPS server using tcp with Zero MQ. I don't control the GPS server.

The gps server sends : $GPGGA,143949.8330,520168215,N,00831.385282,E,,,,173.856,M,,,,*26

But when i print the result, my client have splitted the answer:

$GPGGA,143949.8330,5201

68215,N,00831.385282,E,,,,173.856,M,,,,*26

I can't say wait for 123 bytes of data since the NMEA string can vary in size.

This is my code :

```
#include <zmqpp/zmqpp.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(void){

    const std::string endpoint = "tcp://127.0.0.1:3000";

    // initialize the 0MQ context
    zmqpp::context context;

    zmqpp::socket_type type = zmqpp::socket_type::pull;
    zmqpp::socket socket(context, type);

    socket.connect(endpoint);


    while(true){

        std::string data_str{""};
        socket.receive(data_str);

        std::cout << data_str << std::endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can I solve this issue without stitching the strings together ?

Thanks

Comment: _"Can I solve this issue without stitching the strings together ?"_ Is that really a problem? If yes explain why please.

Comment: Normally the server sends the the data string in one piece. Shouldn't I get this string in one chunk ?

Comment: Have you tried to use a Ethernet Spy to check how the NMEA messages are transmitted through TCP ? ([RawCap.exe](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap) allow to capture localhost Ethernet frames).